# How to generate context menu with the following code

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins

With this code, I am getting JSON data but I just want to show a context menu..
Can you modify this code..

```
    switch (htmlTagName) {
        case 'a':
            alert('a'+'isShiftExists:'+isShiftExists+'length:'+jQ(this).parents('td').find('div.wb_sm_m').length);
            if (jQ(this).parents('td').find('div.wb_sm_m').length > 0 && isShiftExists != -1) {
                //loop json array to build context menu
                jQ(this).parents('td').find('div.wb_sm_m').each(function() {

                    var jsonArr = JSON.parse(jQ(this).text());  //jsonArr contains the json array
                    alert(JSON.stringify(jsonArr));
                //loop items of the json array to find context menu item and link
                //                        jQ.each(jsonArr, function(key, val) {
                //                    
                //                            });
                });
            }
            break;

        case 'td':
            alert('td'+'isShiftExists:'+isShiftExists+'length:'+jQ(this).find('div.wb_sm_m').length);
            if (jQ(this).find('div.wb_sm_m').length > 0 && isShiftExists != -1) {
                //loop json array to build context menu
                jQ(this).find('div.wb_sm_m').each(function() {

                    var jsonArr = JSON.parse(jQ(this).text());  //jsonArr contains the json array
                    alert(JSON.stringify(jsonArr));
                });
            }
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this context menu [plugin](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/09/jquery-context-menu-plugin/) and the [demo](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-contextMenu/demo/) page for context menu implementation.